# Reading dynamically characters in C with a scanf in a loop

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C and I'm trying to read dynamically characters. I want to save them into an array to be able to use it later. What I have gotten for now is this and I don't understand why it's not working. My issue is that I have to press enter twice and it will only save one character.

```
char temp;
char tempOld;
int i = 0;
char string[80];

while(scanf("%c", &temp) == 1 && tempOld != '\n')
{
    string[i] = temp;
    tempOld = temp;
    i++;
}

string[i] = '\0';
```

The point of my exercise is to not use `string.h` or `scanf("%80s", string)`...

Thanks !

Comment: "it's not working" is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Just edited my post !

Comment: because your loop condition `while(scanf("%c", &temp) == 1 && tempOld != '\n')` first reads a character and then afterwards checks if the previous character was a newline.  You you have to read one extra character after the newline for your loop to terminate.

Comment: I see... I really don't know what went through my head. It works fine now, thanks ! I'll post the code to eventually help others.

Comment: BTW: With `char string[80];`, code should not use `scanf("%80s", string)`.  Perhaps  `scanf("%79s", string)` or even better `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition `while(scanf("%c", &temp) == 1 && tempOld != '\n')` first reads a character and then afterwards checks if the previous character was a newline.  Additionally, the value `tempOld` is not initialized so the behavior at the first loop iteration is actually undefined.

You need to check if the current character read was a newline, and if so, then terminate the loop.  Something like:

```
int temp;
while (i < 79 && (temp = getc(stdin)) != EOF && temp != '\n')
{
    string[i++] = temp;
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call scanf to read keyboard input. This code suggests

```
while(EOF != (temp = getc(stdin)) && tmpOld != '\n')
```

Also, initialize tmpOld to something or the compiler might happily remove the whole loop.

Anyway I found `scanf()` to be a sufficient pain in the behind that I stopped ever using it and only ever using `sscanf()` with strings that I've already verified are in the right format.

Comment: OP updated the post -- so this answer doesn't answer his question: *My issue is that I have to press enter twice*

Comment: @MFisherKDX: I think it still applies. `scanf` does dumb things reading from keyboard like drop the rest of the line.